# How do weapon upgrades work?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify my weapons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53565/how-do-i-modify-my-weapons)

I have found several weapon upgrades and a weapon upgrade bench.

I presume that I add the upgrades to weapons I already have in my possession, or how does it work?  Are these upgrades removable so that I can use them on a different weapon later?