# Picked up mods in the opening levels of Mass Effect 3...where are they?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify my weapons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53565/how-do-i-modify-my-weapons)

I picked up several mods in the opening levels of mass effect 3 (PC version). Where are they? They do not show up at the workbench or armory in the Normandy, is this a glitch or am i missing the obvious?